# Is it possible to preserve hardware watchpoint across re-runs in the same gdb session?

Tags: c++, gdb

Suppose I start a gdb session, and create a breakpoint and run.

After I break, I create a watchpoint based on the memory address of a symbol in the current execution, and delete the original breakpoint.

Some time later, I interrupt the program with `Control-C`, still inside gdb, I issue the `run` command to restart the program from the beginning.

However, I would like to preserve the hardware watchpoint across the restart of the debugged process.

Is there a gdb setting that allows me to preserve hardware watchpoints across reruns?

---

Update: Here is an example to reproduce the problem.

```
int main(){
    int NeverGoOutOfScope = 0;
    NeverGoOutOfScope = 7;
    while (1);
}
```

Here are the sequence of `gdb` commands.

```
break 3
run
watch NeverGoOutOfScope
info watch 
run 
# After this point, the breakpoint remains but the watchpoint is gone.
info watch
```

Is it possible to preserve the watchpoint without having to recreate it?

Comment: aren't they preserved by default?

Comment: Nope.  The watchpoints disappear.  The breakpoints may be preserved.

Comment: I'm getting the warning `Error in re-setting breakpoint NUMBER: No symbol "variable_name" in current context`, but it leaves the watchpoint in the breakpoints list: `NUMBER    hw watchpoint keep y variable_name` and its value is getting printed in the next run...

Comment: Is there any simple way to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I'll update when I get back on the computer.

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg, I have updated with an example.

Answer (score 2):

It should work with two conditions: first, that you disable address space randomization; and second, that you use `watch -location`.

To disable randomization, use:

```
(gdb) set disable-randomization on
```

I think this is the default, so you might be able to skip this.

Next, use:

```
(gdb) watch -location NeverGoOutOfScope
```

This will record the address of the variable in the watchpoint.  This is almost always what you actually want -- gdb has some fancy code to re-evaluate watchpoint expressions when a variable goes out of scope, but in practice I think this is more confusing than helpful.

This approach works for me on your test, though I have to ignore a few hits of the watchpoint during process initialization.

Comment: too bad, it is not working for me, riscv rv64g.